# Center a <span> relative to container div, align another span with right-aligned text left of it

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to align a `span` element in the center of a container `div`, and have another `span` with right-aligned text aligned left of it:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| <div>                                                  |
+----------------------+----------+                      |
| <span>               | <span>   |                      |
|                      |          |                      |
|                      |          |                      |
|                      |          |                      |
|        right-aligned | centered |                      |
|                      |          |                      |
|                      |          |                      |
|                      |          |                      |
|                      |          |                      |
+----------------------+----------+                      |
|                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

The contents of both spans are dynamically generated, so I'd like to avoid any absolute pixel widths if possible.

Any idea how to achieve this type of layout?

Here is the markup I eventually went with based on Persinj's answer:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <span class="nav-aside">Right-aligned:&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="nav-menu">centered</span>
  <span class="nav-aside"></span>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav.navbar {
  display: flex;
}
span.nav-aside {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
span.nav-menu {
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I left the vendor prefixes out of my markup since I have limited browser requirements, and I'm relying on autoprefixer to take care of that. Please see the accepted answer if you need them.

Comment: show us your markup and relevant css that you've tried so far...

Comment: Ok, current markup added. I've tried several ways but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Flexbox design / layout

This can be sloved using flex:

Setting tree boxes: 
Aside, center and a hidden one, will fill the required space.
Setting  a `flex-grow` will make make them take up different parts of the page.
Setting `flex-grow: 1;` on each will make them take up equal space. 
Setting one of them to `flex-grow: 0.5`; will give this part less space to grow.
Adding a wrapper with the flex property we can use `align-items:center` to make sure they stay in the center of the wrapper.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/n431sppn/1/)

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.center,
.aside,
.not-shown {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.center {
  flex-grow: 0.5;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
}

.aside {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 50px;
}

.not-shown {
  visibility: hidden;
  flex-grow: 1.5;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="aside">
    aside
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    center
  </div>
  <div class="not-shown">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it only slightly differently as I wanted the width of center column to fit to contents, but this solved the problem. I'll edit the original question to show the markup in case someone else needs it.

Comment: The different display properties are not there for run. There for **new** browser support. I have not added the old style prefixes.

Comment: Thanks. The page already works on all my target browsers and I use autoprefixer, so I just added a comment to my markup.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="span-left">right-aligned</span>
  <span class="span-center">centered</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.span-left, .span-center { display: inline-block; }

.span-left {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: right;
}

.span-center {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Alternatively, use `display: block` and `float: left;` on your spans (don't forget to clear after the wrapper).

Comment: This aligns the text correctly, but span-center is not in the center relative to wrapper, but span-left and span-center together get centered.

Comment: Seems to align span-center correctly if I leave the CSS I had for wrapper out. But I need span-center to be sized according to dynamically generated contents. I tried display: block and float:left, but didn't get that working either.

Comment: Hi, yupp, my solution only works when using `span-left` and (!) `span-center`. Just imagine a `span-right` to be there with the same size as `span-left`, so your center span is aligned correctly (width of `span-left` + `span-center` + `span-right` has to be 100%).

Comment: I got it. Thanks, but unfortunately I don't know the needed relative size of center/left beforehand, so I went with the flex box solution.